# How to query delta of failed queues, render it in Grafana as line graph and send sudden spike alerts via AlertManager?

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql, prometheus-alertmanager

I have an Prometheus exporter that produce metrics like [this](https://pastebin.com/raw/2m2GfQv9). In case that link becomes inaccessible, here is the gist of it:

```
87005 @1649731510.398
87005 @1649731540.398
87005 @1649731570.398
```

That's the result of my metric here:

```
# TYPE http_request_queue_failed gauge
# HELP http_request_queue_failed The length of the failed queue
http_request_queue_failed{service="api.example.com"} 87005
```

What I wanted to do with it are:

1. Render a line graph in Grafana - showing the hourly ups and downs of failed queues (x-axis of the graph must follow the timeframe selected on Grafana dashboard)
2. If there are n failures from a month ago, I don't care. But if there is a sudden spike (say by 1,000), I want to get alerted (as well as graphed) via AlertManager (I know how to create AlertManager rule, but not specifically for this case/expression)

I did some research about this and I found about `delta`, `idelta`, `offset` and etc. But I don't know how to proceed. My queries were:

```
// Query 1
delta(http_request_queue_failed{exported_service="api.example.com"}[1h])

// Query 2
sum by (exported_service) (delta(http_request_queue_failed{exported_service="api.example.com"}[1h]))
```

[image]

[image]

I don't think what I'm doing is correct because I don't see 8,000 increment/decrement in my failed queues. There's only around 760 increment. Not 8,000 as per in my graphs above.

How can I achieve two points above?